# What is the meaning of (0, someFunction)() in javascript

Tags: javascript

I found this code in someone's code, it sound like this:

```
(0, function (arg) { ... })(this)
```

After I try to play around like below,

```js
(0, function (arg) { console.log(arg) })(2);
console.log((0, 1, 2, 3));
(0, function plus1 (arg) { console.log(arg + 1) }, function plus2 (arg) { console.log(arg + 2) })(5);
```

I found that it will always return last item in the bracket.

I wonder what is the name of this programming pattern and what is the use case?

Comment: It’s the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) and it’s useful for confusing people.

Comment: Yeah, I can see no practical reason for this in that situation... the `0,` is literally worthless

Comment: Looks like instead of using IIFE directly, this person wanted to make himself look smart :)

Comment: `it’s useful for confusing people` - best description ever

Comment: And for interview questions, or for trying to make yourself indispensable since no one understands your code

Comment: A comment from waaay in the future: The answer is you're probably looking at transpiled code that used an arrow function `() => {console.log()}`. To make the function call while also dropping the "this" reference, the transpiler converted it to the `(0, fn)(...args)` style you see now.

Comment: Webpack is also bundling some of my code into this format.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In this particular case it seems superfluous, but sometimes this approach is useful.

For example, with `eval`:

```js
(function() {
  (0,eval)("var foo = 123"); // indirect call to eval, creates global variable
})();
console.log(foo);            // 123
(function() {
  eval("var bar = 123");     // direct call to eval, creates local variable
})();
console.log(bar);            // ReferenceError
```

It's also useful when you want to call a method without passing the object as the `this` value:

```js
var obj = {
  method: function() { return this; }
};
console.log(obj.method() === obj);     // true
console.log((0,obj.method)() === obj); // false
```

Also note that, depending on the context, it might be the arguments separator instead of a comma operator:

```js
console.log(
  function(a, b) {
    return function() { return a; };
  }
  (0, function (arg) { /* ... */ })(this)
); // 0
```

In this scenario, `(0, function (arg) { /* ... */ })` are the arguments (`a=0, b=function (arg) { /* ... */ }`) to the function

```
function(a, b) {
  return function() { return a; };
}
```

rather than the comma operator. (Then, the `(this)` at the end is function call with argument `this` to the returned function `function() { return a; }`. But this part is not relevant to the comma operator/argument separator difference)

Comment: ... you just gave me a bunch of other reasons to claim that JavaScript design is broken...

Comment: Wouldn't a better and more readable way to do your second example be `obj.method.call(window)` ?

Comment: @Whelkaholism It should be `obj.method.call(undefined)` if you want it to be equivalent in strict mode too. But that requires the function to inherit `call` from `Function.prototype`. Not all callable objects inherit from `Function.prototype`, and even if they do, `call` could be shadowed.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this works? It appears that javascript wraps a function reference with another function whose first parameter is scope or context? What could you use to replace the 0 that would make the above express true again?

Comment: @latj `obj.method` produces a reference, and thus when you call it, the base `obj` is used as the `this` value. But when you use the comma operator (it doesn't matter whether you use `0` or whatever), the reference is resolved into a value.

Comment: I have been coding for 10+ years,  really can't understand this....

Comment: the eval expression
`(function() { (0, eval)("var foo = 123"); })();`
is equivalent to
`(function() { eval.call(this, "var bar = 123"); })();`
.

Answer (score 3):

It is a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) wrapped with a [self-executing anonymous function](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/). However, I have no idea as to why the meaningless `0` was included except for [obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) purposes.

Answer (score 3):

typical example could be,

```
for(var i=0,j=10; i < j; i++){
 // code ...
}
```

[comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) would evaluate expressions from left-to-right and return result of right most expression

```js
// e.g.

var a = 1, b= 2, c = 3, d = function(){ console.log("a => " +  a) }()
```

Comment: I think the `var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3` is not a "comma operator" but a var declaration. `a`, `b`, and `c` here are created in the local scope so they each are actually declared with a `var`.

To illustrate, here's 2 functions:
`function foo(){var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;}`
`function bar(){var a = (1, b = 2, c = 3);}`.

If you run `foo();`, `a`, `b`, and `c` would only exist in the local scope.

However, if you run `bar();`, you'll find `b` and `c` in the global scope! This is because the `(1, b = 2, c = 3)` portion is now your "comma operator".

Comment: This was the source:
https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/6524-the-confusing-comma-in-javascript.html
Under the section "This Is Not The Comma You Are Looking For"

Comment: _Now_ I get it - I guess I needed this connection to something I know of (usage of commas in a declaration).