# What do similar double brackets mean ()()?

Tags: javascript

For the first time I met this method of setting a variable. I'm a little tangled up with double brackets.
What does this mean?

```js
var defaultState = (0, _state2.default)(servicePath, stateOptions);
```

Comment: Where have you seen the code. Can you please tell the purpose and context of code?

Comment: I seen it in feathers-vuex https://www.npmjs.com/package/feathers-vuex

Comment: Maybe next link can help to understand when that can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40967162/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-code-0-function-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(0, _state2.default)` is an expression which contains comma operator. It evaluates to its last operand. Here `_state2.default` is last operand. So

```
(0, _state2.default)(servicePath, stateOptions);
```

Is same as

```
_state2.default(servicePath, stateOptions);
```

The second brackets call the function with two arguments.

The first `()` are used to group an expression. While the second `()` are used to call the function.

Comment: But why would we use it like this? We can call `_state2.default(servicePath, stateOptions);` directly, or `(_state2.default)(servicePath, stateOptions);` if we want to keep the brackets.