# Is the first factor in the anonymous function of React Hooks transposed into ES5 always 0?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, babeljs

I am interested in ES6 and ES5 transpiring using React and Babel.

If you look at the picture above, the hooks converted to es5 style are called as anonymous functions, why is the first factor is 0?

[image: Original ES5 Code]
[image: transfiled ES5 Code]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40967162/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-code-0-function-in-javascript I could find the answer to my question here.

Comment: https://2ality.com/2015/12/references.html#references-in-real-world-code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does babel rewrite imported function call to (0, fn)(...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275135/why-does-babel-rewrite-imported-function-call-to-0-fn)